# JAXB episode compilation with include does not work

Tags: java, xml, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb-episode

I have 2 schemas A, B. I'm reusing some A elements in B.

**I do not use namespaces.**

I'm using

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0</version>
```

I have have defined an inclusion of schema A in schema B as:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="classpath:my.schema.A.xsd"/>
```

and the catalog as

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "classpath:my.schema.A.xsd" "maven:my.schema:schema-a!/A.xsd"
```

The jaxb configuration goes:

```
<configuration>
    <generatePackage>my.schema.b</generatePackage>
    <schemaIncludes>
        <includes>B.xsd</includes>
    </schemaIncludes>
    <episodes>
        <episode>
            <groupId>my.schema</groupId>
            <artifactId>schema-a</artifactId>
        </episode>
    </episodes>
    <catalog>src/main/catalog/catalog.cat</catalog>
</configuration>
```

The issue is that whenever I specify the episode dependency the schema does not generate any classes even though it contains some B elements I want to generate the classes for.

```
[INFO] Parsing input schema(s)...
[INFO] Compiling input schema(s)...
[INFO] Cleaning package directories.
[INFO] Finished execution.
```

When I remove the episode it works well and generates classes for schema A as well - which I indeed want to avoid.

Do you have any suggestions?

A sample was published in [Jaxb episodic compilation](https://github.com/the-foreigner/jaxb-episodic-compilation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've checked your example. The problem is that you don't use namespaces.

Check your `META-INF/sub-jaxb.episode` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings map="false">
      <jaxb:package name="schema.episode.a"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings scd="person">
      <jaxb:class ref="schema.episode.a.Person"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

You see this `<jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">` and then `<jaxb:schemaBindings map="false">`. This basically tells XJC "don't map anything in the empty namespace". Since your second schema (`b.xsd`) also does not use namespaces, when you use `a.xsd`'s episode file (binding above), you suppress generation of code for `b.xsd` as well.

To sum it up, when using episodes/separate schema compilation you can't put schemas with one namespace into different episodes. This is exactly the issue with `include`.

This is not a bug in the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`. I would not also call it a bug in XJC. It's just how episodes work by default.

See my pull request [here](https://github.com/the-foreigner/jaxb-episodic-compilation/pull/1), it demonstrates episodic compilation, when namespaces are handled accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mentioned I don't use namespaces in the second sentence. I will try with map="true".

Comment: Setting map="true" in the episode file worked for me.

Comment: Completely removing `<jaxb:schemaBindings map="false">` from episode file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` here.

My guess would be that your episode says something like "don't compile namespaces A and B". Please check the binding file inside `META-INF` in your JAR.

This is pretty advanced usage, there's quite a number of points where this can go wrong. You use:

- catalogs
- Maven artifact-based schema resolution
- episodes

Catalogs and episodes are XJC features, Maven resolution comes from the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`.
We should try to single out what fails:

- Try it just with episodes - extract your schemas and compile "as is", without catalogs and resolver
- Just catalogs - extract schema and rewrite to local dirs instead of `maven:`
- Try `maven:my.schema:schema-a!/A.xsd` as schema location without episodes and catalogs

Obviously another three combinations to try.

If you provide a sample project, I'll investigate (but not within the next 10 days). The best would be to file an issue. I'll be moving the plugin to GitHub so this would be a good place:

https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin

Comment: I'm not sure what option I should look for in the episode. I'm pretty sure the catalog is resolving the schema correctly from the jar.

I published a sample under https://github.com/the-foreigner/jaxb-episodic-compilation Thanks!