# JAXB with central XSD structure and without namespaces

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I do have a common.xsd like this

**common.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="Common">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Firstname"/>
            <xs:element name="Lastname"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

where I just define one complex type *Person*.

Now I have two other xsds (house.xsd and car.xsd) and both **include** the common.xsd (not importing).

**house.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="House">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Owner" type="Person"/>
                <xs:element name="City">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Name"/>
                            <xs:element name="ZIP"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**car.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="common.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Driver" type="Person"/>
                <xs:element name="Color"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I want that JAXB generates the Java classes for the three xsds like this:

commons.xsd --> de/hauke/common

house.xsd   --> de/hauke/house

car.xsd     --> de/hauke/car

So I started with the common.xsd file with the following command

```
 xjc -p de.hauke.common common.xsd -extension -episode common.episode
```

and received this episode file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings map="false">
      <jaxb:package name="de.hauke.common"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings scd="~Person">
      <jaxb:class ref="de.hauke.common.Person"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The java classes are also generated correctly under de/hauke/common

The next step would be generating the car.xsd java classes with this command

```
xjc -p de.hauke.car car.xsd -extension -b common.episode
```

But I don't get any errors but I also dont get any classes. This onle output is

```
Ein Schema wird geparst ...      (schema will be parsed ...)
Ein Schema wird kompiliert ...   (schema will be compiled ...)
```

What I am doing wrong? Is that possible with including xsds or is that only possible with importing xsds? But the importing is not a option because we don't want any namespace prefixes in any xml documents.

Thanks Hauke

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself:

the episode should looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings map="true">
      <jaxb:package name="de.hauke.common"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings scd="~Person">
      <jaxb:class ref="de.hauke.common.Person"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The map attribute should be true and then it works like a sharm.

Thanks to this link:
[JAXB episode compilation with include does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728801/jaxb-episode-compilation-with-include-does-not-work)